# React + Redux : When using a redux reducer, Is the use of prevstate necessary if we want to rely on previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, reducers

Using Redux, if we want to rely on previous state to change the value of current state, don't we need to use the prevstate callback function like we do when we call a regular setState `setstate(prevstate => !prevstate.boolean )`? (if we wanted to change the value a boolean inside the state depending on previous value of boolean for exemple).

So is the exemple below OK ? there won't be any batched setState or something that would cause a "twitchy" state ?

```
const initialState = {
  showToolbar: false,
};

const toolbarReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_TOOLBAR":
      return {
        ...state,
        showToolbar: !state.showToolbar,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default toolbarReducer;
```

I hope my question makes sense !

Thank you !

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redux reducers you don't need to worry about a callback to ensure you're working with the latest state because there's no behind the scenes batching of the updates.

Each Redux action/state update is executed when it's called.

Comment: It might also be good to note that when a component that relies on `state.showToolbar` calls `"TOGGLE_TOOLBAR"` during render, it will cause an infinite stream of updates

Comment: There's nothing here that inherently creates loops. Sure you could create an infinite loop somewhere else in your code, but that seems beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I realize that it doesn't inherently create loops, although since @Tan-Aki worried about this, it might be good to give a reason this might happen (since I have seen people make this mistake before and wonder why it crashed their app)